# Unable to login into Kylo

Tags: kylo

While logging into Kylo getting this below error under `/var/log/kylo-ui/kylo-ui.log`.

```
2017-12-07 16:03:52 ERROR http-nio-8400-exec-8:JerseyRestClient:383 - Failed to process request /v1/about/me
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1020)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
```

Comment: Could you also post your /var/log/kylo-services/kylo-services.log file?

Comment: This issue was tagged in this url: https://kylo-io.atlassian.net/browse/KYLO-694     but the status is won't fix, and i tried /apps/kylo/setup/sql/generate-update-sql.sh this one also but still facing the issue.

Comment: I am using kylo.0.8.3v
/var/log/kylo-services/kylo-services.log 
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid default value for 'modified_time' [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE kylo.FEED (id BINARY(16) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255) NULL, FEED_TYPE VARCHAR(45) NULL, created_time timestamp DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL, modified_time timestamp DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' NOT NULL)] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'modified_time' –

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Invalid default value for 'modified_time'` indicates that the default value isn't valid in the server's timezone. Timestamp columns are stored in UTC and have a minimum value of `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. If your server's timezone is IST, for example, then it would covert the default value to `1969-12-31 18:30:01` and that would fail since it's less than the minimum value.

The fix is to increase the default value. For Kylo's purposes a value of `1970-01-02 00:00:01` should be fine.